# Resumeable upload from client JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, file-upload, google-cloud-platform, filereader

I'm trying to understand if there currently is any way to do resumeable uploads (for example to a Google Cloud Storage bucket) from a web client. Looking at FileReader it does not look possible (for big files). Do I miss something?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check the Cloud Storage official documentation for resumable uploads, either for the [JSON API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/resumable-upload) or the [XML API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/resumable-upload). You'll basically need to request a resumable session URI to Storage in a first HTTP request and actually upload the file to that URI in a second request, via jQuery's ajax method for example.

You'll see that you'll need to authenticate your request via a bearer token when requesting the resumable session URI. As explained in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49036222/4926605):

> You'll either need to have your customers use their own Google credentials (unusual, but makes sense for a third party tool for managing someone else's Google Cloud resources) or use some form of signed URL or similar feature.

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of that. I am asking how to call this on the client side with JavaScript (for a resumeable upload).

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand the documentation. There is a "slice" method that can be used here, but it is on the File object. See for example "Reading local files in JavaScript - HTML5 Rocks", https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/